# mod_rewrite not finding index file?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I have made a mod_rewrite condition that will just add a parameter to the `index.php` file. Here it is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(electronic|classical|reggae)$ index.php?genre=$1
```

When I do `mydomain.com/electronic` the rule will recognize an attempt to load the index file, but it returns with a `404` that says

```
The requested URL /media/sde1/home/www/[mydomain].com/public_html/index.php was not found on this server.
```

The funny part about that error is the file path listed above points directly to the root index file on my server.

Anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: Where is this rewrite rule located? The "requested URL" in the error message looks very strange - the full path shouldn't be there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding:

```
RewriteBase /
```

After `RewriteEngine On`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `RewriteBase`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(electronic|classical|reggae)$ index.php?genre=$1 [L]
```